# Direct limit of modules: a property.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Suppose $A$ to be a ring and $M_i$ the indexed $A$-modules used to build the direct limit of modules $M \doteq \lim{M_i}$. Let $f_{ij}: M_i \to M_j$ the transition maps and $\phi : M_i \to M$ the projection map.

> Show that every element in $M$ is of the form $\phi(m_i)$ for an $m_i \in M_i \subseteq \oplus_{i \in I}{M_i}$

My attempt follows.
Let $m \in M$, then is can be written as $[(m_1,m_2,....m_n,0,0,0,..)]$ (finite non-zero components - I wrote it in that way just for simplicity).
In order to be written as a $\phi(m_k)$, I want to see that its class is equal to $[(0,0,0,..,m_k,0,...)]$, in other words there exists a $t$ such that $f_{1t}(m_1)=....=f_{hn}(m_n)$ - but I simply don't see: why is it true?
I am quite sure that I am misunderstanding something.

Thank you in advance.
Cheers

Comment: You seem to use some very ugly "definition" of the colimit?

Comment: Dear @MartinBrandenburg, I am not sure to have understood the meaning of your comment (sorry - my English... :) ). In any case, I use the definition given by wikipedia.

Comment: **can you use Def. of Rotman?** With Def. of Rotman, this is "Lemma 5.30" of Rotman.

Comment: @user1 I don't have the Rotman's book :( Exact title?

Comment: i dont know how to post a pic. in comment. would you like it as an answer?

Comment: @user1 Yes, you should make me a favor. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Rotman*'s book: "*An Introduction to Homological Algebra*" has:

[image]

And

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works!Thank you very much!

Comment: you are welcome very much! :)